# Hiding Navigation Bar Line in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

How can I hide this annoying bottom line on the NavigationController in SwiftUI? I've found solutions for UIKit but nothing for SwiftUI so far. This is what I've tried:

```
var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
                ...
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .onAppear {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
            UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
            UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your full code for your view.

Comment: Where are you applying those methods?

Comment: Just hide navigation bar at all and place that close button as standalone into top leading corner.

Comment: @Asperi the nav bar is needed, I just want to hide the line

Comment: @MrDeveloper posted